# ASP.NET MVC & C# problem, data anotations arent working and I need a maxlength property and validation message

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My ASP.NET MVC data annotations aren't working for me, I don't know why, can someone help me? I want to put a max length property on a number text box and it doesn't work, please help, thanks. I want the text box have a maxlength of 7, 13, etc, and a validation error, I added 2 screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIWeZ.png)

Comment: since it's a number, do you actually want max = 9999999

Comment: i want max length of 7 digits only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

max length is not for number type, you will have to make it one of the supported types or use max = 9999999 (seven 9's)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: what about data anotations? they arent working

Comment: those annotations like @class are exposing html5 properties for you.  To be sure of which one you are using, you can hit f12 in the browser, click the element and verify.